# Spring Data JPA: How to join two entities using annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two entities(Student and Project) and want to join them by foreign key *"student_id"*

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Long student_id;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Project> projects;
}
```

Simply, I want to get students with project list when I send GET request to Student repository.

For example;

```
// > json for POST to Project
{
    "title":"java",
    "student_id":1
}
```

```
// > json for POST to Student
{
    "name":"Bill Gates"
}
```

What I expect to see when I send GET request to Student is simply like this below;

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"java",
      "projects":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "title":"java"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is it applicable using only JPA annotations? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's applicable. 
First, you need to change the student_id to student class like this in your Project class

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id",nullable = false)
private Student student;
```

Second, you need to add 'map' parameter to you oneToMany annotation

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
private List<Project> projects;
```

and that's it.

Side note: you can also consider manytomany relationship if more than one student can be assigned to the same project

Comment: Hi Hesham, thanks for quick answer, but i guess it will end up with an infinite loop since "Project" entity calls "Student" and "Student" calls projects again. That's why I want to use a long variable "student_id" as a foreign key.

Comment: You can use lazy as a fetch type like this  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)@JoinColumn(name = "student_id",nullable = false)
private Student student;

Comment: this will solve the infinite loop problem if there is any. also keep in mind the the post request to the project endpoint will be like that  {
    "title":"java",
    "student":{"id":1}
}